# Crystal Reports - Dynamic Cascading Parameter based on another parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 2008 and have a cascading parameter that pulls data from a table that has ~35,000 rows.  It creates entries off of 5-6 different columns which can total about 12,000 rows.  The values that are returned are not static and change due to re-orgs and such that happen once a month or so (such as some name changes and so forth).

```
Effective Date, Area, region, state, city, store, employee
```

Is there a way to pull the corresponding set of 12,000 records based on the period without turning the "table" into a 100,000+ behemoth that would take several minutes to pick parameters?

I would like to have it pick the period the data is for (Effective Date), then pass that value to the stored proc that drives the dynamic cascading parameter.

EDIT:

Here is a sample of what my data looks like

```
EffectiveDt   Area       Region   State   City     Store        StoreID
5-1-13        Northwest  NW-1     OR      Bend     KMart#1153   1153-42
5-12-13       Northwest  NW-1     OR      Bend     KMart#1124   1124-31
5-11-13       Northwest  NW-2     CA      Faar     Burgerss     8245
6-5-13        Northwest  NW-1     OR      Bend     KMart        1153-42
6-12-13       Southwest  SW-4     AZ      Hawt     Bally        9352
6-17-13       Midwest    MW-3     OK      Windy    Nails        3524-1
```

So I do not want to have to try to add Effective Date in the complete set.  The Effective date sort of drives what is picked and I want to pass that in without including the effective date in the cascading parameter set.

The parameter list the user has to pick from would look like:
    Northwest
    Southwest
    Midwest

Then drive to each lower level from that.

I'm confused on how to base this cascading parameter list without adding another column with the effective date.

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on `5-6 different columns which can total about 12,000 rows`?

Comment: From my experience if your cascading parameter datasource also has parameters, you need to prompt for those on your own and then push the data into the report. This is what I had to do using the CrystalReportViewer web control...it might not be required on the Desktop version.

Comment: Will the report be published to BusinessObjects Enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a command to retrieve the LOV for the parameter. Add the dates for the period as parameters for this command. When you run the report it will try to run the command and will find that there are parameters for the command. The report will show parameters' dialog for the period, when you set the period it will run the command and show another parameters' dialog to choose the actual report parameters (including the dynamic one). In this dialog the LOV for the dynamic parameter will contain just values within the period set in the first  parameters' dialog.
So what you are trying to do is possible but you will get 2 separate prompts for parameters. If you choose wrong period you cannot go back and change it, you will need to cancel the report and run it again.

Another option is to use a viewer, which supports real cascading parameters. The only one I know is demonstrated here: [Video](http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_CascadingParameters.aspx). You can add your dates as parameters in the viewer (not necessary to change the report) and the dynamic parameter will be recalculated when dates are changed.